# Pyton get fem solving simple 2D differential equation?

Tags: finite-element, numerics, differential-equations

I need to solve the differential equation:

$$u_t = \Delta u + \sin t$$

On a 2D domain with homogeneous Dirichlet boundary conditions. Tod o this I am trying to use the python package getfem.

I am struggling quite a bit trying to set things up especially the parts of $u_t$ and $\sin t$ as I am not sure how to define them based on the [docs](https://getfem-examples.readthedocs.io/en/latest/demo_unit_disk.html#Initialization).

If I understand properly this:

```py
import getfem as gf
import numpy as np
import math
import pyvista as pv
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display


center = [0.0, 0.0]
dir = [0.0, 1.0]
radius = 1.0
angle = 0.2 * math.pi

mo = gf.MesherObject("cone", center, dir, radius, angle)

h = 0.1
K = 2
mesh = gf.Mesh("generate", mo, h, K)

# Select boundary.
outer_faces = mesh.outer_faces()
OUTER_BOUND = 1
mesh.set_region(OUTER_BOUND, outer_faces)

sl = gf.Slice(("none",), mesh, 1) #Turn mesh into triangles

mfu = gf.MeshFem(mesh, 2)
elements_degree = 2
mfu.set_classical_fem(elements_degree)
```

Will give me a cone mesh for the domain (a triangle). Which is what I want. And the line:

`mfu = gf.MeshFem(mesh, 2)`

Is creating an mesh with a 2D vector field on top of it (I think?).

Then I can do this:

```
md = gf.Model("real")
md.add_fem_variable("u", mfu)
```

To introduce the variable I am solving for.

But from here on out I don't know how to set up the equation and tell getfem to solve it.

Comment: This equation cannot be right. $u_t$ is a scalar, but on the right hand side you have $\nabla u$, which is a vector. Did you mean $\Delta u$?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Thank you for catching that, yes it was a typo on my end sorry.

Comment: Hmm... looks like a diffusion equation with a uniform source sinusoidal in time; I bet for a simple domain there is analytic solution for this problem.

Comment: @MaximUmansky there probably is but I need to solve it numerically with the package. This is a learning exercise.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FreeFEM++ converting equation into code](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/42540/freefem-converting-equation-into-code)